# How do I get my Cake Wallet to sync?

Tags: synchronization, wallet, remote-node, cakewallet

Recently I created a Cake Wallet account and sent Monero to it.  However, whenever I try to sync it, it continues to say  "Starting Sync."  I have tried connecting it to various different nodes but none of those have worked either.

Also, every time I add a different node, it shows up with a red dot beside it.  This happens even if the node works outside of the Cake Wallet.  Is this a known bug?  Or is there something I can do to fix any of this?

Comment: same for me on iOS, it does not finish sync even if app left running in iPhone background. Did you found solution? I will try to restore wallet on Haven linux wallet...

Comment: No.  I haven't found a solution yet...

Answer (score 1):

If no nodes work at all, then it is probably an issue with your internet provider blocking connections to the nodes. You can try a VPN, using Tor, or a different network connection.

https://guides.cakewallet.com/docs/bugs-service-status/connection-issues/

Answer (score 0):

It must be firewall-related. Either yours or, more likely telecoms. They tend to block "mining operations"..